# Unable to download app from xbox store after recent update

Tags: uwp, xbox, xbox-one

I've UWP app published on PC and xbox store, after update to xbox store, I am unable to find the app. App is not released for public audience only for internal Beta testing.

Is there anyone who is facing similar issue and if you know any trick to install app please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the update you mentioned? Did you submit a new version of your app or do you mean the update of Xbox system? Also, could you please check the state of your app in the partner center?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT: state of app in partner center shows published in store. I can download and install from PC store but not from xbox store. Please note that app is beta released for internal users only. do you mean the update of Xbox system? Yes, recently xbox store has been updated and since then facing this issue. MS has screwed this with their new update. Existing apps which are released to public has no issues.

Comment: It should not hide the beta test package. I'd suggest you open a free [support ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) about this. Choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic, and select App submission for issue type.

Comment: @roy yes I submitted ticket and MS support team says they don't find any issue in my app. So asking for video to send them but don't know how i take video in xbox using steps recorder available for Windows 10 pc

Comment: You could ask the ticket support about which way they'd like to capture a video in case they have special requirements about the video.

Answer (score -1):

If your app isn't for Public Audience, you couldn't access to it in Xbox STore with normal user behavior (search by app name, ...).

Go to your partner center --> Products --> {YOUR APP ENTRY } --> Product identity

and copy the URL of your app (or the store protocol link) in your Edge App on Xbox One and the Xbox Store will show your app
[image: Partner center]

PS: For my dev, I host a simple page on netlify with the Store Passwork link for quick access from Xbox device.

For apps with whitelisted users, the link must be retrived at the following line in your partner page :
[image: Private store link]

Comment: I know private app is not available to all users. Ofcourse I whitelist the email and then try tofind the app. Also As I mentioned problem is not in pc store only in xbox store.

Comment: My answer is for Xbox Store and my experience is for Xbox too.
I develop an app used on PC and Xbox One and I've a beta test app with private audience mainly used for tests on Xbox.
No need for that kind of negativity, I just try to help you :)
Just an important point : 
Even if you are logged with your whitelisted email on your Xbox, you cannot find your app in the Xbox Store with search. You must passed by the link show in your partner space. It's only by this way !

Comment: does not work with link as well on xbox store. Negativity is in your mind, not in my words :)

Comment: My bad. For my test app with list of whitelisted accounts, i was just one problem. When I add a user to test group for the app, the new user wasn't authorized to see the app. Maybe a new submission will resolve the problem of this user add. I wasn't investigate and use another account. Is it your case ?